# If first input == something then output something [Second attack on a grid]

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

My code output's suggested coordinates after an input but I have no idea how to have an output based on the first output so say someone inputs B4 and the program suggests the user to attack B3, B5, A4 or C4 when they input one of these suggestions I need it to print the third and final suggestion without using a bunch of if statements. ex if Attack1== "A1" and Attack2== "A2":
   print ("The last hit is A3 " + Rank + " " + Name + ".")

```
Rank= input("What is your rank?")
Name= input("What is your name " + Rank + "?")
grid= input("What would you like the length of your grid to be " + Rank + " " + Name + "?")
Attack1=input("Where do you want to attack first " + Rank + " " + Name + "?\n" +"(Please print with capital letters)")
grid= int(grid)
#Removing the Number from the Letter
RemoveNum = Attack1[0].upper()

#Removing the letter from the coordinates
RemoveLetter = Attack1[1].upper()

RemoveLett=int(RemoveLetter)

row = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10".split()
col = "A B C D E F G H I J".split()

x=col.index(RemoveNum)
y=row.index(RemoveLetter)

possibles=[] # blank list to store suggestions in

if x > 0 :
    possibles.append(col[x-1] + row[y]) # left
if x < grid-1:
    possibles.append(col[x+1] + row[y]) # right
if y > 0 :
    possibles.append(col[x] + row[y-1]) # up
if y < grid-1:
    possibles.append(col[x] + row[y+1]) # down

# Construct string of all possibles except the last
poss_list = ','.join(possibles[:len(possibles)-1])



#Printing First Suggestions
print("You could try {0:s} and {1:s}".format(poss_list,possibles[-1]))
```

Comment: Use dictionaries to implement a state transition table.

Comment: @Barmar may you please elaborate :)

Comment: You have a dictionary that maps inputs to the action that should be taken. The value could be another dictionary if more inputs are necessary. Eventually the value would be a lambda that specifies an actual result like printing a message.